# Babel shorthands do not expand correctly after a temporary switch to other language. Bug?

Tags: babel, languages, shorthands

I cannot better describe the problem than by the MWE below.

**Steps for reproduction:**

1. Create a bi-lingual article with Babel (here: american and ngerman)
2. Add the Babel shorthands for the German language to English (I do that often for my convience to enable `"=` for English, too.)
3. Use the shorthand in a sectioning command.
4. Switch language locally.
5. Use the shorthand in a sectioning command again.

**Actual result:** In step 3 the shorthand is correctly expanded in the heading and the TOC. In step 5 the shorthand is correctly expanded in the heading, but the TOC prints the shorthand literally.

**Expected result:** The shorthand should always be expanded correctly.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[american]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,american,main=american]{babel}

\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasamerican{\languageshorthands{american}\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Lore"=ipsum}

The section title \verb#Lore"=ipsum# is correctly typeset in the TOC.
The shorthands work in the heading and in the TOC.

\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
Ein Absatz in deutsch.
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{Lore"=ipsum}

After a temporary switch to a foreign language, the shorthands work only partially.
The section title \verb#Lore"=ipsum# is correctly typeset in the heading but not in the TOC.
Why?

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No bug; you're stating `\useshorthands{"}` in the wrong place:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,main=american]{babel}

\addto\extrasamerican{%
  \languageshorthands{ngerman}%
  \useshorthands{"}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Lore"=ipsum}

The section title \verb#Lore"=ipsum# is correctly typeset in the TOC.
The shorthands work in the heading and in the TOC.

\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
Ein Absatz in deutsch.
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{Lore"=ipsum}

After a temporary switch to a foreign language, the shorthands work only partially.
The section title \verb#Lore"=ipsum# is correctly typeset in the heading but not in the TOC.
Why?

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the problem? Using `\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}` causes `\babel@toc{ngerman}{}` to be written in the `.toc` file; then `\end{otherlanguage}` causes the writing of `\babel@toc{american}{}`.

Now the sequence `\babel@toc{ngerman}{}\babel@toc{american}{}` causes `\noextrasngerman` to be evaluated, which contributes

```latex
\bbl@deactivate {"}\umlauthigh \bbl@nonfrenchspacing
```

and you see the problem. By adding `\useshorthands{"}` in `\extrasamerican`, the problem is solved.

Comment: OK. I followed [this answer by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484313/47156) where the `\useshorthands{"}` is outside `\addto\extrasamerican`. Also Ulrike Fischer adds `\languageshorthands{american}` explicitly which is omitted in your answer.  Is `\languageshorthands{american}` required or not?

Comment: @nagmat84 `\languageshorthands{american}` does nothing, because no shorthand is defined to begin with. And unfortunately, the answer you cite is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Use the starred version of `\useshorthands`, ie:

```
\useshorthands*{"}
```

From the manual: “User shorthands are not always alive, as they may be deactivated by languages (for example, if you use " for your user shorthands and switch from german to french, they stop working). Therefore, a starred version \useshorthands*{char} is provided, which makes sure shorthands are always activated.”